# package fancyhdr: no dot behind chapter number in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using a university template and want to modify it just a little bit.

How can I remove the dot behind the chapter in the headings?

Here is a "minimal" example.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4 , twoside=false, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}

\usepackage{type1ec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc\leftmark}}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newcounter{romancount}
\setcounter{romancount}{\value{page}}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Introduction}
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{romancount}}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\addchap{List of Abbreviations}                 %adds a chapter without numerating it
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{}          %add the name of the chapter to headings

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit

changing to a more simple fancyhdr setup like

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

and then removing the dots with the mentioned code is not working for me, because it also changes the style of the header. And I don't want to change the appearance of the template

my setup

[image]

simpler but changed setup

[image]

isn't there a way of leaving my setup/the template as it is and just remove the dots?

Comment: I think you should start by incorporating the answers to the other questions you have asked on this site today.  The fancyhdr code you include above is out of date (belonging the fancyheadings package), and egreg has shown you a correct version.

Comment: I don't know if you "feel" to change to `titleps`, but see my edited answer to see how it is simple to use.

Comment: @karlkoeller I really like your solution! Here, the only problem is the problem I have in the other thread: Now all pagenumbers of pages who are not fanncy (abstract, ALL first pages of chapters, appendix) are not affected and therefore have normal sized page numbers. How can I change them also to footnoted pagenumbers? (@all: sorry for these two threads I will merge them when I have finished this work)

Comment: @BenjaminMassow In my answer they are changed to footnote size.

Comment: @BenjaminMassow If you want to do that with `fancyhdr` add this in the preamble: `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, make `\leftmark` consist of just the chapter heading by adding:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
```

This line should be placed after `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Next, use the new `\leftmark` to make a header in the desired format.

```
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ \leftmark}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can highlight code by selecting it and clicking the button marked `{}` above the text field. This will indent blocks by four spaces, or enclose words in backticks (`\``).

Comment: Thanks! I am indeed new here, although I've used the answers on the forum many times before. It looks a lot clearer now.

Comment: :-( I do not get it run with my code. Can u assist me?

Comment: I noticed there was an extra \ in the 'Without dot' code. That might be the problem...

Comment: recognized and removed it, didn't work. Have u got it run in my posted overall code?

Comment: Made some modifications to the answer, to make the implementation clearer. I did run it this time and it did work for me.

Comment: @GrowMyHair Great, it worked. So there is another problem I have mentioned in the other post: All page numbers at pages where a new chapter begins (and where is no header) are bigger (normalsize) than at all the others (footnotesizes). How can I modify their size at all pages not beeing fancy?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to deal with the complexity of `fancyhdr` hacking, you can switch to the [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package, which is really simpler to manage.

Try the following example

```
\documentclass[paper=a4 , twoside=false, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}

\usepackage{type1ec}

\usepackage{titleps}

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
  \sethead{} % left
          {} % center
          {} %right
  \setfoot{} % left
          {\footnotesize\thepage} % center
          {} %right
}

\newpagestyle{fancy}{%
  \sethead{} % left
          {} % center
          {\footnotesize\scshape\chaptername~\thechapter~~\chaptertitle} %right
  \setfoot{} % left
          {\footnotesize\thepage} % center
          {} %right
  \setheadrule{.4pt}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newcounter{romancount}
\setcounter{romancount}{\value{page}}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Introduction}
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

which gives the desired headings

> [image]

and desired footings in footnote size, even in `plain` pages.

### EDIT

You can change

```
          {\footnotesize\scshape\chaptername~\thechapter~~\chaptertitle} %right
```

to

```
          {\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\chaptername~\thechapter~~\chaptertitle}} %right
```

if you want this result:

> [image]